# Axis bank Geniusoay payment gateway integration in Opencart 2.0.3?

Tags: php, opencart

How can I integrate `query_dr` from Axis Bank into OpenCart 2.0.3 GeniusPay Axis Bank module?

I have already enabled pg and have it working, but now a few of the transactions were not tracked (any payment transaction details).

So bank wants me to upload some new query dr files.

I don't have any idea how to to upload those files because those files are written in normal PHP, and in OpenCart, we have a framework.

I need help with this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can post your query in opencart commercial support forum. If you wish  to get the help here you need place some code and explanation what you have done and where you got an errors...

Comment: you can use this opencart axisbank module

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=12275